# How can I get Google Music Beta outside of the US?

Tags: google-play-music

Google's [Music Beta](http://music.google.com) is a dream come true, except I'm in the UK:

> We're sorry. Music Beta is currently only available in the United States

Obviously I can't just go via a proxy and set up a new account in the US as I need it on the account I have and that I'm currently using with my phone. How can I get Music Beta on my phone?

Comment: can you then tell us why it's only avalible in US? is it your own choice or has it something to do with law?

Comment: The law is certainly part of it. Now that the major record labels are involved this is even more true. They have their "rules" which are different in every country and require separate negotiation. I expect them to move quickly to try to launch in other countries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Information on this is understandably thin on the ground. However, it appears that it is only the registration process that checks your country of origin.  If you use a proxy to obtain an invitation code you should be able to link that with your current Google Account.

However, as the information is pretty sketchy at the moment I would use caution if you are going to attempt to do this.

Other than that, you will have to wait until Google release the service in the UK.

Comment: I've signed up to receive an invitation, I'll let you know how I get on from there if I get one.

Comment: Your might also need a US visa for the payment. Thats how Apple does AppleTV.

Comment: HotspotShield worked great for invitation/sign up.

Answer (score 4):

I used a US proxy (from Germany) and got my invite yesterday. Everything works great for now, I only needed the proxy for registration.

Comment: This is what I did. Worked great.